# c#error cs0029 for service reference soap

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

Hello I add a service soap in c# and I instantiated a class of the service.

Now I find myself in a situation where I need to add data into the service.

The main class this:

```
public partial class Pippo: object, System.ComponentModel.InotifyPropertyChanged {
 private Pluto[] plutoField;
}
```

if I press F12 on the Pluto class, another class called like this is called:

```
public partial class Pluto: object, System.ComponentModel.InotifyPropertyChanged {

private string aaa;
private string bbb;
}
```

to recall the class I first instantiated the class like this but when I have to insert data it gives me an error:

```
Pippo ppp = new Pippo();
Pluto plt = new Pluto();

plt.aaa = "aaa";
plt.bbb = "bbb";

ppp = plt; <-- here is the error
```

The error in question is the following:

Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Pippo.Pluto' to 'Pippo.Pluto[]’

How do I enter data into Pippo?

Thanks in advance for the answer

---

Comment: Which line in the code shown is producing that error?  I'd expect the code shown to have multiple errors, but not that error.

Comment: you are absolutely right the error appears to me when I do this: ppp = plt

Comment: But the code shown wouldn't produce *that* specified error on that line.  It would produce a *different* error.  It would also produce errors on the two lines before it because `aaa` and `bbb` are `private` and can't be assigned a value from outside the class.  The code shown would likely also fail because there is no `System.ComponentModel.InotifyPropertyChanged` (notice the casing).  It seems like the code shown isn't the code you're using at all, but rather text that might kind of look like the code you're using.

Comment: Why are you expecting `ppp = plt;` to work? They're differently typed objects... that's like doing `apple = orange` or `anIntegerVariable = aStringValue`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access private members of a class, you can change the member accessor to `public`, add public member functions, or use reflection. Here is an example about reflection:

```
    public class Test
    {
        private String Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Test test = new Test();
        var Name = test.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        Name.SetValue(test,"Nick");

        String value = (String)Name.GetValue(test); 

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

`BindingFlags.Instanc` is used to search for member instances, including fields and methods and `NonPublic` is used to search for members of non-public methods.